# Some properties of the homology of tensor products of chain complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, tensor-products

This is essentially part of the proof for the algebraic Künneth formula. Let us suppose that we have a chain complexes $Z_*,D_*$ of R-Modules and $Z_*$ consists of free modules and has trivial differential. Now my professor states the following two properties

1)$$ H_n(Z_*\otimes D_*)\cong \bigoplus_{p+q=n}H_q(Z_p\otimes D_*)$$

2)$$ \bigoplus_{p+q=n}H_q(Z_p\otimes D_*)\cong \bigoplus_{p+q=n}Z_p\otimes H_q(D_*) $$

For 1) one shall use the triviality of the differential and for 2) that $Z_p$ is free for all p. Attempt to prove 1):
We have
$$H_n(Z_*\otimes D_*)\cong \frac{ker(\partial:=\bigoplus_{p+q=n}(-1)^p x \otimes \partial^{D_*}y:Z_p\otimes D_q\rightarrow Z_p\otimes D_{q-1})}{im(\partial:=\bigoplus_{p+q=n+1}(-1)^p x \otimes \partial^{D_*}y:Z_p\otimes D_q\rightarrow Z_p\otimes D_{q-1})} $$
Maybe you can pull the $Z_p$ out here, but there is just too much going on for me there. For the second one i dont have an idea.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: If Z has trivial differential, it is a direct sum of complexes with exactly one nonzero component. Tensor products and homology commute with direct sums

Comment: Okay so let me try to formalize this...We write $Z_*\cong \bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}Z_n[+n]$. Then you would need to show that direct sums of chain complexes commute with tensorproducts of chaincomplexes. And then one uses your fact and gets the first equality. Do you have references for all these facts? And the second one you can do simlarly i guess? You write $Z_p\cong R[S]$ and then write $Z_p$ considered as a  chain complex as the direct sum of chaincomplexes that just have R in degree 0. Then use your fact again. Is that correct?

Comment: You do not need references: just prove them!

Comment: Okay, well if i knew how i would not be here...but i will give it another shot.

Comment: You sure know how to prove that $(A\oplus B)\otimes C$ is isomorphic to $A\otimes C\oplus B\otimes C$ for *modules*: this is exactly the same.

Comment: Of course. I thought that homology commuting with direct sums would be quite difficult. I will try it at the weekend and if i am succesfull i will write an answer here.